# Sliding doors buttons not clicking properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [CSS sliding doors](http://css-tricks.com/examples/Sprites+SlidingDoors-Button/#) and when I try to attach an event handler to it, it doesn't seem to get triggered because of the span within the anchor.

I have the same CSS as the above link, with a class called 'button':

```
<a href="#" class="button"><span>Submit</span></a>
```

When I click on the far right side, it works, which is outside the span.  But when I click on the span, it doesn't

I'm attaching an event handler like this:

```
$('.button').live('click', function(e){ 
    alert('click');
});
```

Any suggestions for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you add the click event to the span itself.. that way the event might bubble up to the anchor tag..

Comment: It's probably CSS related. I do this hundred of times and add listeners to it without any problem. Could you create a fiddle or share the css?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the event listener on the span instead.

```
$('.button span').on('click', function(e){ 
    alert('click');
});
```

Comment: The span is part of the CSS solution to give the button effect the OP requires.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuMrT/2/). It works.
It maybe in the CSS.

Also, I changed "live" since it's deprecated.

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {alert('click')});
```